# shorten if statement with file_exists condition

Tags: php, if-statement

How could I shorten this if statement?

```
if(file_exists($path1) 
   || file_exists($path2) 
   || file_exists($path3) 
   || file_exists($path4)
  )
```

Comment: Do you want to make it harder to understand?  Or are there (many) more than 4 paths being checked? You can put the paths in an array and use a loop - but that won't be shorter.

Comment: I would consider spending effort on this task only if a large number of paths need to be checked, in which case @AD7six [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028036/shorten-if-statement-with-file-exists-condition#comment35179597_23028036) is the way to go.

Comment: I need to check many files that could exist in over 10 paths. So I'm afraid of using a loop. Is there any other solutions in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put all of your files in an array, you can map the function to it. You can find whether or not all of the values are true by using [`array_product`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php):

```
$path = Array("path/file1.php","path/file2.php","path/file3.php","path/file4.php");
$check = array_product(array_map("file_exists",$path));
```

---

I misread, I thought you wanted to check that all files exist, make the following changes to ensure at least 1 exists:

```
$check = array_sum(array_map("file_exists",$path));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a large no of paths (N number) then you can use this code

```
$ARR_PATHS  = array($path1, $path2, $path3, .......... , $pathN);

$process = false;
foreach($ARR_PATHS as $path)
{
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
       $process = true;
       break;
    } 
}

if($process)
{
     // continue your code if any one of the path is exists
}
```

Above code is not shorter the if statement. it will helpful when you have N number of paths or dynamical generated paths (N is dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use a loop with arrays if you have a lot of paths that you want to check.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($path);$i++
  if(file_exists($path[$i]))
     //do something..
```

other than that I don't think you can shorten the statement or its condition unless you want to remove some path checks.